# MX lookup failed

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dns-zone, cloudflare

This is a part of my dns-zone file:

```
;; MX Records
mx.domain.de.   300 IN  MX  1   direct.domain.de.

;; CNAME Records
www.domain.de.  300 IN  CNAME   domain.de.
mail.domain.de. 300 IN  CNAME   domain.de.
direct.domain.de.   300 IN  CNAME   domain.de.

;; A Records (IPv4 addresses)
domain.de.  300 IN  A   5.**.**.***
```

After 24h i scanned my domain with http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx. I alway get this:

"No Records Exist". I use Cloudflare, so that is wrong with my dns-zone file? All works fine, expect the MX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an MX record cannot be pointed to a CNAME.
You need to create an A record for Your MX.

RFC 2181

```
10.3. MX and NS records

   The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part of
   the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias. [....]
```

source: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181.txt

Comment: read the whole RFC if You are setting the zone file yourself :) You may find more surprises :D

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the CNAME problem Bartłomiej pointed out, your MX record also has a "mx." prefix on the domain. This means it applies to email addressed to "name@mx.domain.de", not "name@domain.de". So, your MX section should simply be:

```
;; MX Records
domain.de.   300 IN  MX  1   domain.de.
```

Comment: If i can, i would give you also a "right answear". thanks, now it works, really! :D

Comment: I will mark as usefull myself :) I agree the record had to be adjusted too.